# How to tell if a button hasn't been pressed after a certain amount of time in pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

```
button = Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji = "◀️", custom_id = "button1")

view = View()
view.add_item(button)

async def button_callback(interaction):
    await message.edit(content="**response 1**")
  
button.callback = button_callback

await message.edit(content="⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀", view=view)
```

I want to be able to check if the user has pressed the button, and then do something if the button hasn't been pressed after a certain amount of time. How can I check if the button hasn't been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) function of the `asyncio` package.

```py
import asyncio

event = asyncio.Event()

async def button_callback(interaction):
    await message.edit(content="**response 1**")
    # Button has been pressed, set the event
    event.set()

button.callback = button_callback

# Wait for the button to be pressed, or for 5 seconds to pass
try:
    await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), timeout=5)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    # Button wasn't pressed within 5 seconds, do something
    pass
```

If wasn't pressed within a certain timeout it will raise a `TimeoutError` which you can handle appropriatly.

Or you use `threading` so it won't stop and wait, but continue with the main code.

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time

# Flag
button_pressed = False

async def button_callback(interaction):
    # set button pressed
    global button_pressed
    button_pressed = True
    await message.edit(content="**response**")

button.callback = button.callback

def check_button_thread():
    global button_pressed
    # if you want to use message
    # global message
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        # Check button
        if button_pressed:
            # Reset flag
            button_pressed = False
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
        else:
            # Check for the timeout
            elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            if elapsed_time > 5:
                # you need to set message global if you want the below
                # await message.edit(content="**button not pressed")
                # do other stuff....
                break
        time.sleep(0.1)

button.callback = button_callback
check_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_button_thread)
check_thread.start()

# all other stuff here

# wait for the seperate thread to finish
check_thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

A View can have a timeout method which you can use to do stuff.

See the [guide](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/buttons#timeouts) on how to do this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).